# Spring Batch moving file after processing

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing

I am new to Spring batch.

I have to read multiple files(delimiter) from a folder and load them in DB. Which I did.

But my issue is after each file is processed I have to move the file to `processed` folder or error records to `Error` folder.

For example if I process a below file (`abc.txt`) from multiple file:

```
D|hello1|123 
D|hello2|three - Error 
D|hello3|123
```

I know that 2nd record is an error.

Now I have to write the error record in a error file(`abc-error.txt`) to error folder and proceed with the next record. After the file is processed successfully excluding error records, i need to move the `abc.txt` to a processed folder.

How can I achieve the above requirement?

My job:

```
<batch:job id="file_to_db">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet ref="moveFiletoTmpFolder" />
        <batch:end on="FAILED"/>
        <batch:next on="*" to="step2" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="step2">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager"
            start-limit="100">
            <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="databaseItemWriter"
                commit-interval="100">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
<bean id="multiResourceReader"
        class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="resources" value="file:batch/csv/processing/*.csv" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="cvsFileItemReader" />
</bean>
```

The job is not one step. But each file must be moved once it is processed.
Error records must be written into a separate file named `filename-error.txt` for each file.

Comment: Is it a single step job? If possible show your job & step configuration.

Comment: Teja, you can achieve by adding another step with a tasklet that does the moving part. Refer "archiveFileTasklet" part here: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2458888/spring-framework/open-source-java-projects-spring-batch.html?page=4

Comment: @The Guest, Tasklet is used for doing the operation once. But for me i need to move the file to different folders after reading each file from many files.

Answer (score 1):

Listeners.  Spring Batch has a collection of listeners for injecting this type of logic into just about any point of the step or job you could need.  Depending on where the error is discovered will indicate which listener is appropriate.  For example, if the error is discovered during reading, implementing the `ItemReadListener#onReadError` method would make sense.  In general, this type of logic is commonly handled by implementing the correct listeners to execute the required logic at the right point in the process.

You can read more about some of the listeners provided by Spring Batch in the reference documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#interceptingStepExecution